# Automatically clear old data

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible automatically to clear old data in Influx DB? Let's say some configuration option to keep records for 1 month only? In my server I store quite much statistics, so preventing running the free storage out I would like to have such feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's simple, just add shard with Retention on 7 days.

Comment: So the data will be removed after 7 days?

Comment: Yep, and you can use Duration options to split shards. http://cl.ly/image/0c3L1X1x302X
And BTW, in next version of influxdb 0.9(it's steel beta) you can use Retention Policy inline in set query.

Comment: @ezotrank any document for inline set query?

Comment: [http://influxdb.com/blog/2014/12/08/clustering_tags_and_enhancements_in_0_9_0.html](http://influxdb.com/blog/2014/12/08/clustering_tags_and_enhancements_in_0_9_0.html) API cleanup section