# InfluXDB Raspberry: send data periodically to logging host

Tags: influxdb

I would like to use InfluXDB wit my Raspberry/Openhab home automatisation.
I am just worried about db size/performance.
So my plan would be: log only 1 month on Pi, let it be cleaned automatically.
Clean I understand is easy with retention. ([Automatically clear old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232406/automatically-clear-old-data) )

For long time anaylsis I want to collect all the data on a server.
Now question: How can I export the data on PI before retention into flatfile and afterwards import that data in a seperate InfluXDB on different server?
(Or even better: is there a way to do this in a sort of cluster mode?)

thanks a lot,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I use InfluxDB on a pi for sensor logs. I log now 4 records every 5 seconds for more than 3 months and performances on my pi are really good. I don't have now the file size but was not more than 10Mb

You can use InfluxDB in cluster mode but not sure it will answer yor question for data cleaning.

To exprt data, you can use InfluxDB API to get all series in the data base, then all data and flush that in a json file. You can use the API to load that file in another DB